# Minimax function for Nimsticks Game (Python)

Tags: python, minimax

Here is my brief: 'Nimsticks is a turn-taking zero-sum game for two players. The game state consists of one or more
piles of sticks. On their turn, a player may take 1, 2 or 3 sticks from any one pile. The player who
takes the last stick is the loser of the game.

The state will be a tuple containing two parts: the current state of the piles, and who’s turn
it is (1 = MAX, 2 = MIN). For example, if there is a pile of 3 sticks and 2 sticks, and it is Max’s
turn to play, then the input should look like ([3, 2], 1)
minimax_value(([3,2],1))'

So far I have a partial solution (below), but it only returns 'inf' or '-inf' which isn't ideal. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
import copy

def minimax_value(state):
    if (state[0] == []):
        return(result(state))
    else:
        if (state[-1] == 1):
            return(max_value(state))
        else:
            return(min_value(state))
    
def terminal(state):
    if (state[0] == []):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def result(state):
    if (state[-1] == 1):
        return("+1")
    else:
        return("-1")

def max_value(state):
    if terminal(state):
        return result(state)
    else:
        v = float("-inf")
        for c in next_states(state):
            v = max(v, min_value(c)) 
        return(v)

def min_value(state):
    if terminal(state):
        return result(state)
    else:
        v = float("inf")
        for c in next_states(state):
           v = min(v, max_value(c))
        return(v)

def next_states(state):
    if (type(state) == tuple):
        piles = copy.deepcopy(state[0])
    else:
        piles = copy.deepcopy(state)
    pilesSave = copy.deepcopy(piles)
    temp = []
    newList = []

    for x in range(0, len(piles)):
        for y in range(1, 4):
            piles[x] = piles[x] - 1
            if (piles[x] >= 0):
                temp = copy.deepcopy(piles)
                newList.append(temp)
        piles[x] = pilesSave[x]
    return(newList)


print(minimax_value(([4], 1)))
```

Comment: You name your players min and max?

Answer (score 1):

`min_value` calls `max_value` on each `next_states(state)` which likewise calls `min_value` on each `next_states(state)` because `next_states` returns a list of values less than the given value this process repeats until `state = [0]` at which point `next_state` returns an empty list because `if (piles[x] >= 0):` evaluates to `false` and because `next_states(state)->[]` nothing inside `for c in next_states(state):` happens and `return (v)` returns `inf` or `-inf`. Because `min_value` returns `inf` to `max_value` `max_value` returns `inf` and visa versa for `max_value` returning `-inf` for `min_value`.